# Javascript: if something is in URL set cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have a problem. I need set cookie, when in the URL is "pecan", and text will be "do 30min". If in URL isn't "pecan" or cookie expire text will be "nad 30 min".

Cookie expire in 30min (this is 1/48).

I have this code:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
if(window.location.href.indexOf('pecan') != -1)
{
    Cookies.set('ent_afil', 'one', { expires: 1/48 });
}

if (Cookies.get('ent_afil') == 'one')
{
    document.write('do 30min');

}
 else {
    document.write('nad 30min');
}
</script>
```

But still no function.

Where is mistake?

Thank you.
Pavel

Answer (score 0):

```
function getCookie(name) {
  const value = `; ${document.cookie}`;
  const parts = value.split(`; ${name}=`);
  if (parts.length === 2) return parts.pop().split(';').shift();
}

if(window.location.href.indexOf('pecan') != -1)
{
              var now = new Date();
               var minutes = 30;
               now.setTime(now.getTime() + (minutes * 60 * 1000));
               cookievalue ='one'+ ";"
               document.cookie="ent_afil=" + cookievalue;
               document.cookie = "expires=" + now.toUTCString() + ";"
               <!--document.write ("Setting Cookies : " + "name=" + document.cookie );-->
}
var value=getCookie('ent_afil')
if(value == 'one')
{
    document.write('do 30min');

}
 else {
    document.write('nad 30min');
}
```